# Cell output controlled by CellFrameLabel Checkbox?

Tags: dynamic, notebooks

The following generates a `Cell` that returns the state of the checkbox when evaluated:

```
CellPrint[
  ExpressionCell[
    {DynamicModule[{val=True}
      , Checkbox[
          Dynamic[val, (val=#; SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], TaggingRules->{"value"->val}])&]
        ]
      ]
    , Dynamic@CurrentValue[{TaggingRules,"value"}]
    }
  , TaggingRules->{"value"->True}
  , Evaluatable->True
  , CellEvaluationFunction->(CurrentValue[{TaggingRules,"value"}]&)]
]
```

[image: Works]

Moving the checkbox into the frame label breaks the functionality. Why?

```
CellPrint[
  ExpressionCell[
    Dynamic@CurrentValue[{TaggingRules,"value"}]
  , TaggingRules->{"value"->True}
  , CellFrameLabels->
    {
      {ToBoxes[
        DynamicModule[{val=True}
        , Checkbox[
            Dynamic[val, (val=#; SetOptions[Print[FullForm@EvaluationCell[]];EvaluationCell[], TaggingRules->{"value"->val}])&]
          ]
        ]
      ], None}
    , {None,None}
    }
  , Evaluatable->True
  , CellEvaluationFunction:>(Print[FullForm@EvaluationCell[]];CurrentValue[{TaggingRules,"value"}]&)]
]
```

[image: Fails]

Printing the `EvaluationCell[]` shows that `SetOptions` is setting the `TaggingRules` on the `FrameLabel` cell, not the main cell. **How does one update the tagging rules of the main cell from within a frame?**

Answer (score 2):

Given that the objective has been clarified as "*How does one update the tagging rules of the main cell from within a frame*?" here is a solution:

```
CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[Dynamic@CurrentValue[{TaggingRules, "value"}],
  CellTags -> {"X"},
  TaggingRules -> {"value" -> True}, 
  CellFrameLabels -> {{ToBoxes[
      DynamicModule[{val = True}, Checkbox[Dynamic[val, (val = #;
           NotebookLocate["X"]; 
           SetOptions[NotebookSelection@EvaluationNotebook[], 
            TaggingRules -> {"value" -> val}]) &]]]], None}, {None, 
     None}},
  Evaluatable -> True]]
```

**checked:**

We begin with the checkbox checked and the tagging rules "value" for the cell displayed as `True`.

[image]

**unchecked:**

We uncheck the checkbox. The tagging rules "value" for the cell is now set to `False`.

[image]

We can toggle the checkbox over and over to confirm that this does exactly what the OP has sought. You can use show expression if in doubt to verify that the tagging rule has changed locally in what the OP calls the "main cell" -- and not at the notebook level.

[image]

And you can do other things to monitor events. Here we see that the notebook level tagging rules are not affected but the local cell tagging rules change with the value of the checkbox.

[image]

[image]

And so on. In summary the tagging rule in the "main cell" has been updated by checking/unchecking a checkbox located in a cell frame.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the state of the checkbox to the `CellEvaluationFunction`; for example, to toggle reporting of stderr during evaluation of a [`shellCell`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5451304#5451304). Would like to make this a style, so setting the notebook's tagging rules seems out-of-place.

Comment: @JxB well you should completely re-write the question to reflect what you actually want to do -- there is no point in asking a question that is unrelated to what you **actually** want. It wastes everyones time. As it stands you have asked about having a checkbox in the cell frame and I have answered showing that it works.

Comment: ...and in any case changing the checkbox is not a kernel evaluation. `CellEvaluationFunction` requires you to be doing kernel evaluations so you are not going to be able to use variable dynamic control settings. `CellEvaluationFunction` can only take whatever the setting is at the time you evaluate the cell.

Comment: Mike, thank you for your answer. What I actually want to do is stated boldly in the question's body: "How does one update the tagging rules of the main cell from within a frame?" :) Sorry for the confusion, was it the title?

Comment: @JxB right, so `CellEvaluationFunction` actually has nothing to do with your question after all. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @JxB you were provided an answer to what you asked (the bit in in bold type so we could all see it without any ambiguity), and you clarified that use of `CellEvaluationFunction` wasn't really the essence of your question, and then you disappeared :)